# VS Code - automatic namespace name generating

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I format my C++ code, it automatically adds comment with name of the namespace at the end of the namespace. How to turn off this automatically generating namespace comment at the end of the namespace in VS Code ?

Example of my code:

```
namespace test {
   int add(int a, int b) {
       return a + b;
   }
}  // namespace test # i dont want this line
```

Comment: Which programming language are you seeing this in? C++? C#? ...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I use C++

Comment: check the settings of the formatter you use, if they don't have a setting for this add an issue to there repo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the C/C++ extension with a recent version of clang-tidy, then they should be turned off by default. It's controlled by the clang-format setting `FixNamespaceComments: false`. It's possible you're using using another extension to format your code which doesn't have that default or your other clang-format settings are changing the default behavior.